# How to make different rounded corner values in UIView dynamically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to make the different round corners to my view. My views are loading dynamically. Eg: I have 3 views and want to pass the different corner values for each views.

View1 : 
topLeft : 12 , bottomLeft : 12 , topRight : 4 , bottomRight : 4

View2 : 
topLeft : 4 , bottomLeft : 4 , topRight : 12 , bottomRight : 12

View3 : 
topLeft : 4 , bottomLeft : 12 , topRight : 4 , bottomRight : 4

Sample code:

```
extension UIView{

     enum Corner:Int {
        case bottomRight = 0,
        topRight,
        bottomLeft,
        topLeft
    }

    private func parseCorner(corner: Corner) -> CACornerMask.Element {
        let corners: [CACornerMask.Element] = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        return corners[corner.rawValue]
    }

    private func createMask(corners: [Corner]) -> UInt {
        return corners.reduce(0, { (a, b) -> UInt in
            return a + parseCorner(corner: b).rawValue
        })
    }

    func roundCorners(corners: [Corner], amount: CGFloat) {
        layer.cornerRadius = amount
        let maskedCorners: CACornerMask = CACornerMask(rawValue: createMask(corners: corners))
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            layer.maskedCorners = maskedCorners
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            layer.cornerRadius = 8 // Setting static values for the below versions
        }
    }
}

cardView.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], amount: 12).
```

I want to pass the array of the corner values instead of the single value.
expecting to pass like this ratio : [12,4,12,4].

Answer (score 0):

How abount make a struct instead.

```
struct CornerRadius {
    var topLeft: CGFloat = 0
    var topRight: CGFloat = 0
    var bottomLeft: CGFloat = 0
    var bottomRight: CGFloat = 0

    init(_ topLeft: CGFloat, _ topRight: CGFloat, _ bottomLeft: CGFloat, _ bottomRight: CGFloat) {
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.topRight = topRight
        self.bottomLeft = bottomLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight
    }
}

let radius = CornerRadius(0, 8, 10, 11)
```

I'm not sure if it is the answer you want.

Hopes it could help you.

Comment: Yes, we can create a struct. But I want to pass multiple values at a time. Each corner has a different values.

Comment: @Pugal What you need is the way to draw the different corner or just pass the radius values to existing drawing function?? I'm not sure, if you need the way to draw corner, you could use UIBezierPath to draw a Mask, and set the mask to layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it takes only the float value and it doesn't take any other data format. I think I should go for Bezier Path only.